# I add font but they doesn't work (css) @font_face

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, font-face

```
 .writing {
      display: block;
      margin-top: auto;
      margin-bottom: auto;
      text-shadow: 5px 5px red, 10px 10px green, 15px 15px yellow;
      font-family: Niconne;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 150;
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: "Niconne";
      src: url("../fonts/Niconne-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
      /* src: url("../fonts/Niconne-Regular.woff") format("woff");
      src: url("../fonts/niconne-v10-latin-regular.woff2") format("woff2");
      src: url("../fonts/niconne-v10-latin-regular.eot") format("EOT"); */
    }
```

these are my codes. it works fine now but when i put out other sources it turns back to the first point ( it doesn't work). i want to use it locally ( don't give me fontlink)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add quotes to your `font-family`, so it will be like this `font-family: "Niconne"`

Updated Answer:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: "Niconne";
   src: url("../fonts/Niconne-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
   src: url("../fonts/Niconne-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("../fonts/Niconne-Regular.woff") format("woff"),
        url("../fonts/niconne-v10-latin-regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
        url("../fonts/niconne-v10-latin-regular.eot") format("EOT");
}
```

Comment: it's not working :(

Comment: @Asimorobot I updated my answer, try this haha:)

Comment: it worked very fine. but what was the difference? =)

Comment: @Asimorobot The difference is I use multiple format in single src instead of multiple src. Your font face are `src: url(...) format("truetype"); src: url(...) format("woff");` but mine are `src: url(...) format("truetype"), url(...) format("woff");`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change `font-family: Niconne;` to `font-family: "Niconne";`

```
.writing {
      display: block;
      margin-top: auto;
      margin-bottom: auto;
      text-shadow: 5px 5px red, 10px 10px green, 15px 15px yellow;
      font-family: "Niconne"; /* **Change Here** */
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 150;
    }
```